# Using Xamarin Forms, how do I override the back button functionality?

Tags: uinavigationbar, xamarin.forms

Using Xamarin Forms, I have a MasterDetailPage whose Master is a list of menu options and Detail is a NavigationPage that contains a ContentPage.  If I push a second page onto the Detail's NavigationPage, the icon that used to open the menu becomes a back button.  I want to override this behavior so that icon always opens the menu.  I have a subheader with a custom back button which is why I need the Detail to be a NavigationPage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible now

```
NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(page, false);
```

where page is the page you are about to push.

Comment: This currently only works if inheriting from FormsApplicationActivity, not FormsAppCompactActivity

Comment: Xamarin had fixed the issue, it works with FormsAppCompatActivity now

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible out of the box. maybe using a custom render for the Navigation page.

Answer (score 0):

I found there are a lot of ways to make a new screen pop up with the Master Detail Page. The one that stopped the back button from showing up for me was:

```
((MasterDetailPage)Application.Current.MainPage).Detail = new NavigationPage(page);
```

where "page" is whatever screen you want to set it to. For example:

```
((MasterDetailPage)Application.Current.MainPage).Detail = new NavigationPage(new ResultsPage());
```

Comment: That will replace the current detail navigation page with a new navigation page, creating a new navigation stack,which defeats the purpose of creating the navigation page initially.